# Directional cosine of normal unit vector

Tags: differential-geometry, summation

In below directional cosine of binormal unit vector instead of $${l} = \dfrac{y'z''-z'y''}{ \sqrt{(y'z''-z'y'')^2+(y'x''-x'z'')^2+(y'z''-z'y'')^2}}$$ and similarly **m** and **n** DC.
Following term are used using summation
$$l = \dfrac{y'z''-z'y''}{\sqrt{\sum (y'z''-z'y'')^2}}$$

Alternate term used in book

[image]

Could you explain how this terms are replaced with summation?

Comment: You can write $z''$ with `$z''$`.

Comment: Looks indeed like a very old-fashioned book.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an informal shortcut taken by the author. The author apparently literally just wants you to assume that $\sum (y'z''-z'y'')^2$ represents the sum $(y'z''-z'y'')^2+(y'x''-x'z'')^2+(y'z''-z'y'')^2$.

I don't think there is any way to directly infer this if you were only to see
$\sum (y'z''-z'y'')^2$ without any of the contextual clues about what the author intended.
But you **do** know what the correct sum is, so you should remember what it really is each time you see this shortcut in this book.

If the three coordinates were named $x_1, x_2, x_3$ instead of $x,y,z$, then one could write
$$ \sum_{i<j} (x_i'x_j''-x_j'x_i'')^2 $$
as a standard notation for
$$ (x_1'x_2''-x_2'x_1'')^2 + (x_1'x_3''-x_3'x_1'')^2 + (x_2'x_3''-x_3'x_2'')^2. $$